# Native Linux installation on Allwinner tablet

Tags: linux, android, arm, tablet

Is it possible to do a clean install (I mean a native install, just like on a computer) of a Linux distro on an Allwinner a33-based tablet (or more generally speaking on an Android tablet). And if yes, I would like to know how.

Also, as I was searching for more info I saw many tutorials dealing with VNC, but I guess these are not clean installs, am I right?

I am not an ARM SoCs expert, so every information you can provide is useful!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to cross compile the kernel and create a uboot image for your device, hack the tablet to change the boot options and prepare and copy all files to the sd_card.